# String split with parseInt in Java

Tags: java, split, parseint

We are asked to build a constructor for a Stopwatch that takes a string in the format of "##:##:###" and updates minutes, seconds and milliseconds (private instance variables) accordingly. For example, `"1:21:300"` indicates 1 minute 21 seconds 300 milliseconds.

So I am trying to use `string.split()` paired with `parseInt` to update values. However, the program will not compile. My constructor has the correct syntax according to eclipse, but there is something wrong with what I am doing. I have never actually used `split` nor `parseInt`, so I could be using these 100% wrong. Thank you.

```
    public StopWatch(String startTime){
    String [] timeArray = startTime.split(":");

    if(timeArray.length == 2){
        this.minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
        this.seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
        this.milliseconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[2]);
    }
    else if(timeArray.length == 1){
        this.minutes =  0;
        this.seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
        this.milliseconds =    Integer.parseInt(timeArray[2]);              
    }
    else if(timeArray.length == 0){
        this.minutes = 0;
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.milliseconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[2]);             
    }
    else{
        this.minutes = 0;
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.milliseconds = 0;
    }
}
```

P.S. Junit test says "ComparisonFailue: expected 0:00:000 but was 20:10:008" when trying to do:

```
s = new StopWatch("20:10:8");
assertEquals(s.toString(),"20:10:008");
```

Comment: What is your StopWatch.toString()? If you did not define one, you are inheriting the one from Object, which will not do what you want.

Comment: Or if u have one I think you may have problem with leading 0's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, the lengths are off by 1 each each, but the index's you are using in if block are also off; eg. if the length is 1, the only index available is 0, if the length is 2, the index's available are 0 and 1.

Thus you get a constructor that looks like:

```
class StopWatch {
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    int milliseconds;

    public StopWatch(String startTime) {
        String[] timeArray = startTime.split(":");

        if (timeArray.length == 3) {
            this.minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
            this.seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
            this.milliseconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[2]);
        } else if (timeArray.length == 2) {
            this.minutes = 0;
            this.seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
            this.milliseconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
        } else if (timeArray.length == 1) {
            this.minutes = 0;
            this.seconds = 0;
            this.milliseconds = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
        } else {
            this.minutes = 0;
            this.seconds = 0;
            this.milliseconds = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick and helpful answers all around.

Comment: @user2407581 - We kinda hoped that providing enough hints would be sufficient to put you on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your toString() method with:

```
public String toString() {
    String paddedMinutes = String.format("%02d", this.minutes);
    String paddedSeconds = String.format("%02d", this.seconds);
    String paddedMilliseconds = String.format("%03d", this.milliseconds);
    return paddedMinutes + ":" + paddedSeconds + ":" + paddedMilliseconds;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the %02d is. This is only my second semester of programming (and I transferred to a different university between semesters which was a big mistake). I will look into it further though, thank you for the response.

Comment: It's good advice, but the problem is already apparent in the given code.

Comment: @user2407581 `%..d` will be replaced by the string representation of the given digit (d) value. The 2 means max two digits, the 0 tells the processor that the value should be left padded with zero's up to the maximum size (so you always get two digits).

Comment: Or just `return String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d", minutes, seconds, milliseconds);` of course.

Answer (score 1):

Though Java arrays are zero-based, their lengths simply count the number of elements.

So, `{1,2,3}.length` will return `3`.

As your code is written now you will be getting `ArrayOutOfBounds` exceptions left and right.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(timeArray.length == 2){
```

should be:

```
if(timeArray.length == 3){
```

and so on.

20:10:8 split by : will give you a length of 3 ;)